# Android XML Scroll View not scrolling

Tags: android, xml

I have a linear layout that holds a scroll view that holds another Linear Layout which then holds the content. But for some reason, I can't scroll with it? I've tried a NestedScrollView too but that also did not work. I read that you are supposed to use wrap content and I am but still not scrolling. My Code:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/empty_textview"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_m" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/divider" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/empty_textview"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_m" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/empty_textview"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_m" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sponsor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/belgrano"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_detail_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/empty_textview"
                android:textDirection="locale"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_m" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

All help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is due to Scrollview's height itself.

change this

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

to this

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

if that doesn't work, check if the parent of scroll view is giving it enough space. the hierarchy should be like this if you want a scrollable form

```
**Main layout** with match_parent height and width-> **Scroll view** with match_parent height and width -> **Linear/Constraint layout** with wrap_content height and match parent width -> Views to be scrolled
```